# Pyspark2 replace ? in data

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have Question Marks "?" in my data. In my column called "Name". These question marks "?" act as null values in my data. How do I replace the ? with NaN.

Using pyspark2, I tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col

data = data.select(regexp_replace(col("Name"), "?", "NaN"))
```

Is there perhaps another way using a user defined function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character '?' has a special meaning in regular expressions. Use escape sequence. Hope this helps,

```
data = data.select(regexp_replace(col("Name"), "\?", "NaN"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)